# Prove the curve $(x(t),y(t))$ is contained and bounded within a larger square centered at the origin

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm analyzing continuous functions on compact intervals and came up with this question from Arthur Mattuck - Introduction to analysis book. It exactly says:

Let $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ be continuous on $[a,b]$. As $t$ varies over this interval the point $(x(t),y(t))$ traces out a curve in the $x-y$  $plane$.Prove this curve is contained  within some large square centered at the origin and show by example that this might be not true if the interval used in the $x-axis$ is of the form $(a,b)$

My approach:

1. Compactness implies a closed and finite interval. Excluding one of them, then this is not compact and therefore not bounded.
2. Also that a curve is given by $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, but not sure if this is useful.

I don't know how to go over this. If I have to proof by contrapositive or what else. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: circles can be defined implicitly by $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$

Answer (score 0):

There are $c_1,c_2>0$ such that

$|x(t)| \le c_1$ and $|y(t)| \le c_2$ for all $t \in [a,b]$ ($x,y $ are continuous and $[a,b]$ is compact).

let $c:= \max\{c_1,c_2\}$ and $Q:=[-c,c] \times [-c,c] $.

Then: $(x(t),y(t)) \in Q$ for all $t \in [a,b]$.

Comment: So, you meant that there is a bigger set, called $Q$, which has a domain $[-c,c]$ with image $[-c,c]$?
How do I know this is centered on the origin? My intuition says that as it is symmetric
Is not necessary to state also that $|a|, |b|$ is smaller than $|c|$?